# How to write a SQL query to get my desired output?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample data:

Table: Category

```
+--------+--------+
| parent |  name  |
+--------+--------+
| fruit  | apple  |
| fruit  | banana |
| fruit  | grapes |
| fruit  | apple  |
| cars   | duster |
| cars   | swift  |
| games  | nfs    |
+--------+--------+
```

I need to achieve something like this:

```
+-------+--------+---+
| fruit | apple  | 2 |
|       | banana | 1 |
|       | grapes | 1 |
| cars  | duster | 1 |
|       | swift  | 1 |
| games | nfs    | 1 |
+-------+--------+---+
```

i.e. count and grouping in this manner

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: BTW, fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Comment: Fruit and fruits?

Comment: oh! no everythings fruits..

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: i have tried grouping and count.... the result gives me all rows filled i.e fruits apple 2 then fruits banana 1 and so on; i want to have it like fruits appears only once.

Answer (score 1):

Approach using Sql Server (T-SQL)

```
DECLARE @Categories TABLE(

    CategoryName    VARCHAR(MAX),
    Item            VARCHAR(MAX)
)

/*Add data to the tempory table for demo purpose*/
INSERT INTO @Categories( CategoryName, Item )
VALUES  ( 'fruit', 'apple' ),
        ( 'fruit', 'banana' ),
        ( 'fruit', 'grapes' ),
        ( 'fruit', 'apple' ),
        ( 'cars', 'duster' ),
        ( 'cars', 'swift' ),
        ( 'games', 'nfs' );

/*Query to get the result*/
SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CategoryName ORDER BY Item) = 1 
             THEN CategoryName ELSE '' END AS 'Category Caption', 
             Item, COUNT(Item)  AS 'Count'
FROM @Categories
GROUP BY CategoryName, Item
ORDER BY CategoryName
```

Comment: i have applied this same logic but the output is not as expected... still the word "FRUIT" appears multiple times; i want it to appear just once and so on for the rest of the data.

Comment: @AdityaGupta - Updated

Comment: @YogeshSharma - Nope, it is for SQL Server , also I have mentioned that on my Reply..

Comment: @Spider `q` is for `MySQL` & `row_number` not standard SQL

Comment: @YogeshSharma - also there is a tag for SqlServer, did you notice that on the question?

Comment: achieved it by the updated query... thanks spider...thanks everyone!!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN1 , COLUMN2 , SUM(COLUMN3 ) AS QTY
FROM CATEGORY
GROUP BY COLUMN1 , COLUMN2
ORDER BY COLUMN1 , COLUMN2
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the table and insert the records:

```
CREATE TABLE category (element_type char(20), element_name char(20));
INSERT INTO  category VALUES ('fruit', 'apple');
INSERT INTO  category VALUES ('fruit', 'banana');
INSERT INTO  category VALUES ('fruit', 'grapes');
INSERT INTO  category VALUES ('fruit', 'apple');
INSERT INTO  category VALUES ('cars', 'duster');
INSERT INTO  category VALUES ('cars', 'swift');
INSERT INTO  category VALUES ('games', 'nfs');
```

Formulate the Query:

```
   SELECT element_type AS Type,
          element_name AS Name,
          count(element_name) AS Count
     FROM category
 GROUP BY element_type, element_name;
```

Result:

```
Type    Name    Count
cars    duster  1
cars    swift   1
fruit   apple   2
fruit   banana  1
fruit   grapes  1
games   nfs     1
```

Comment: My output must contain a table where no word appears more than once!

Comment: Hi Aditya, This you may do programatically. Simply loop over the SQL result table and manipulate it the way you like it.